# flutter_inappwebview not working to show a video conference site inside my application

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-inappwebview

I am trying to show a video conference site inside my application using `flutter_inappwebview`. Every other URL is working but when I put the conference link these errors pop up:

```
I/BpBinder(22456): onLastStrongRef automatically unlinking death recipients: <uncached descriptor>
I/BufferQueueProducer(22456): [SurfaceTexture-0-22456-15](id:57b80000000f,api:1,p:718,c:22456) connect(): api=1 producerControlledByApp=false
D/EgretLoader(22456): EgretLoader(Context context)
D/EgretLoader(22456): The context is not activity
D/DecorView(22456): createDecorCaptionView windowingMode:1 mWindowMode 1 isFullscreen: true
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity](22456): hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
I/InputTransport(22456): Create ARC handle: 0xb400007ef868c340
W/ContentCatcher(22456): Failed to notify a WebView
E/GPUAUX  (22456): [AUX]GuiExtAuxCheckAuxPath:630: Null anb
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?? I have same issue